# How to enter text in the username&password field in Facebook login window (calabash-android)

Tags: automated-testing, calabash

I am using [Calabash](http://calaba.sh/) Android for automation testing. My app has a facebook login button and after click on it. A web view is opened, how to enter text in usename and password field?

Comment: Are still experiencing any difficulties? Was the answer below helpful?

Answer (score 1):

*There can be at least 2 solutions.*

---

**1st possible solution:**

```
Then /^I login to Facebook with "(.*)" email and "(.*)" password$/ do |email, pass|
  set_text("webview css:'input[name=\"email\"]'", email)
  set_text("webview css:'input[name=\"pass\"]'", pass)
  touch "webview css:'button[name=\"login\"]'"
end
```

---

**2nd possible solution:**

```
Then /^I login to Facebook with "(.*)" email and "(.*)" password$/ do |email, pass|
  touch("webview css:'input[name=\"email\"]'")
  keyboard_enter_text(email)
  touch("webview css:'input[name=\"pass\"]'")
  keyboard_enter_text(pass)
  touch "webview css:'button[name=\"login\"]'"
end
```

`keyboard_enter_text` method here is from [Calabash Android: enter text from keyboard](http://krazyrobot.com/2014/02/calabash-android-enter-text-from-keyboard-using-adb/) post.

```
def keyboard_enter_text(text)
  processed_text = text.gsub(/([^\w\s])/) { |c| '\\' + c }
  processed_text = processed_text.gsub(' ', '%s')
  input_command = "#{default_device.adb_command} shell input text #{processed_text}"
  raise "Could not send keyboard text: #{text}" unless system(input_command)
end
```

Comment: Please tell if this helped or not.